# Collections.rotate not working

Tags: java

I can't get Collections.rotate to work. When I enter qwerty into userInputCharacters and run this code, it just ends up outputting qwerty again. Any recommendations?

```
Collections.rotate(Arrays.asList(userInputChararacter), 2);
for(int index = 0; index <= characterAmount - 1; index++)
    System.out.print(userInputChararacter[index]);
```

UPDATE: Here is my full program.

```
import java.util.*;
public class WrapAround
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException
    {
        //Create a scanner to read the users input.
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Get the amount of characters the user wants to input.
        System.out.println("How many character do you want to enter?");
        int characterAmount = userInput.nextInt();

        //Get and put the user's characters into an array.
        System.out.println("Please enter your " + characterAmount + " characters.");
        String userInputString;
        userInputString = userInput.next();
        char[] userInputChararacter = new char[characterAmount];
        for(int index = 0; index <= characterAmount - 1; index++)
            userInputChararacter[index] = userInputString.charAt(index);

        //Get what number character the user wants to start with.
        System.out.println("Which character do you want to start with?");
        int startingCharacterIndex;
        startingCharacterIndex = userInput.nextInt();
        startingCharacterIndex--;

        //Give the user their characters in order.
        System.out.println("Here are all your characters, beginning with number " + (startingCharacterIndex + 1) + ".");
        userInputChararacter = Collections.rotate(Arrays.asList(userInputChararacter), (startingCharacterIndex - 1));
        for(int index = 0; index <= characterAmount - 1; index++)
            System.out.print(userInputChararacter[index]);
        /*
        for(int index = startingCharacterIndex; index <= characterAmount - 1; index++)
            System.out.print(userInputChararacter[index]);
        for(int index = 0; index <= startingCharacterIndex - 1; index++)
            System.out.print(userInputChararacter[index]);
        */

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please flesh this out into a [mcve].

Comment: This would be helpful for you   http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-util-collections-rotate-method-java-examples/

Comment: believe it or not, i actually used that link already and it still doesnt work.

Comment: Don't use JavaScript snippet tags with your posted code. I removed these from your original post along with a comment in the edit -- why did you re-add them? This isn't JavaScript code.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see a way to add plain old Java code.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it doesn't work is that `Arrays.asList(new char[]{'q','u','e'})` will create a list of size 1, not 3.  It's different from  `Arrays.asList('q','u','e')` where elements will be correctly autoboxed to Character and list of size 3.  Consequently your rotation is not going to change anything.

You should create your own `List<Character>` instance by adding elements or creating a wrapper class for the underlying array.

Or, perhaps easier to eliminate `char` altogether and represent even single chars as Strings.

Comment: For what it's worth, `Arrays.asList(new Character[]{'q', 'u', 'e'})` _does_ have size 3, and swapping `char` for `Character` is probably the simplest fix.